# How to configure Eclipse to always launch the last run configuration, not the current file?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, launch

Back in 2008, around version 3.4, Eclipse changed the default behavior of the Run button to attempt to launch the file with focus, rather than launching the same run configuration that was run the last time.  How do I get the old behavior back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [a post](http://jdcarlflip.blogspot.com/2008/10/eclipse-bringing-back-run-last-launched.html) on *Loving Software Blog*, you change the following preference:

*Run/Debug* -> *Launching* panel; **Launch Operation** section; change radio button to "Always launch the previously launched application".

I've verified that this works in Indigo, the current version.